# How url dispatching works in Plone?

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

In Django there is url dispatcher(urlconf). Does Plone have some url traversing rules? Obviously answer is yes, but what are those rule, can anyone help me through this?

Answer (score 3):

Most of times Plone URLs are mapped to physical objects in its database.

An URL like http://yourhost/Plone/folder/folder/document is automatically available when the folder structure exists.
It just works.

See http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/serving/traversing.html

If you need custom URL to be mapped to something that is not a content you need to develop a *browser view*: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html
In this case you can have something like http://yourhost/Plone/@@your-view-name

If you want to map a view with subpaths you need to define a browser view and manage traversal: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/serving/traversing.html#custom-traversal

In this case there's some gotchas and you don't have a powerful URL mapping like in Django or Flask (commonly in Plone it's better to stay simple and use only simple views).